# Figuring out retention time using clj-kafka?

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka, clj-kafka

Is there a way to discover a Kafka topic retention time during runtime using `clj-kafka`?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for clj-kafka claims that its admin API can retrieve topic configuration, which will contain the retention time if it was configured for the topic. If it isn't configured, the topic will use the default retention time from server.properties on the broker, and unfortunately right now the defaults are not exposed to clients at all.